# Program running but file not opening using open() function

Tags: python, python-os

I am just learning about file manipulation and created a simple 'text.txt' file. This file, as well as my source code('files.py') share the same parent directory('files/'). I am trying to open the file:

```
import os

helloFile = open('./text.txt')
```

However, when I run this at the command line no error is thrown but no file is opened. It seems like it is running with no problem but not doing what I want it to do. Anyone know why?

Comment: What do you mean, "no file is opened"? How do you know? What happens and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the text of the tutorial I am reading makes it sound like this should open the file in textEdit. Is this not the case?

Comment: @user3131132 no, it definitely won't. It `opens` file-like object in a memory

Comment: Try to read the file content with helloFile.read(). If you get the file content in the command line, the file is being opened correctly.

Comment: @py_dude probably should have continued on to the next page before coming here... thanks.

Comment: In a Python context, "opening" a file does not in any way correlate to double-clicking on a file in your file-system and launching the default application. To "open" a file means to get a handle to a resource, with which to do further processing like reading or writing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should probably `read()` from file as you **only created file descriptor object which targets the file**, but didn't really do any operation on it.

also, I recommend you to use

```
with open('./text.txt') as f:
    helloFile = f.read()
```

it will automatically `close` file for you,

in other case you need to close file manually like below:

```
f = open('./text.txt')
helloFile = f.read()
f.close()
```